# My view is not responding to setFrame if it is hidden

Tags: ios

I had a submit button that i initially set as hiding. When I try to adjust the frame of it, i can't seem to get it to move? (The reason i make this assumption is because my keyboard covers the bottom half of the screen and i try to automatically adjust the button if the keyboard is up)

So my hacky fix is to have this code running in the keyboard listener:

```
if (self.submitButton.isHidden) {
    self.submitButton.hidden = NO;
    self.submitButton.frame = CGRectSetY(self.submitButton.frame, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - BUTTON_FULL_HEIGHT);
    self.submitButton.hidden = YES;
} else {
    self.submitButton.frame = CGRectSetY(self.submitButton.frame, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - BUTTON_FULL_HEIGHT);
}
```

is this correct?

Comment: You may want to update your question's title as it doesn't match the real question.

Comment: Did you add this button in a storyboard that's using auto layout? If so, you shouldn't be setting any frames, you should be adjusting the constraints. When the view needs to be redrawn, like when you unhide your button, the button will revert to the frame defined by its constraints.

Comment: nope :( i don't think any storyboards are being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the button i had been using was not UIButton* and the class was something else that overrides the set hidden (and accidentally broke)

but since i dont know how to properly close this question, i'm just going to give a thumbs up to the other answer

Answer (score 1):

You should register to receive `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notifications. These notifications will contain the frame of the keyboard on the `userInfo` using key `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`. Here, you can move your `submitButton` to avoid the keyboard.

Comment: i tried your method and it doesn't work either. i was actually listening to `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and even then, it still doesn't work. however, if i set the button to be temporarily visible before adjusting, it works. i was just wondering if there's a better way

Comment: I've never experienced a button not moving when you set its `.frame` when it's hidden unless I've specifically overridden `.frame` to behave that way. If you log the frame before and after the set while it's hidden, does it get set?

Comment: I'm completely stumped too. It looks like the frame value is indeed changing (to the correct position). however, visually, i'm not seeing my button whenever i call `.hidden = NO` later on (which is getting called at the right times). is it because i'm using iphone 6?

Comment: nvm. it turns out the button i was using wasn't UIButton.